# Finding the smallest/largest values in an interval such that the function equals a given value?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, proof-explanation

> If $v$ is a value of a continuous function $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$, use the least upper bound property to prove that there are smallest and largest $x\in [a,b]$ such that $f(x)=v$.

This question has been posed before ([Find smallest and largest values in a bounded interval such that a function equals a value](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1424507/find-smallest-and-largest-values-in-a-bounded-interval-such-that-a-function-equa)) and there is actually a solution in the comments, most notably the top comment. I was wondering if someone could maybe expand upon that comment (explain it a bit more clearly) and then also elaborate on how without loss of generality, that extends to the smallest value as well.

Answer (score 0):

A topological way to see it :

$$\lbrace x \in [a,b] \text{ }|\text{ } f(x)=v \rbrace = f^{-1}(\lbrace v \rbrace)$$

is closed (as the continuous preimage of a closed set) in the compact $[a,b]$, hence is compact, and non-empty because $v$ is a value of $f$, hence it has a minimum and a maximum.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at the linked question, I'd do it in the following way.

Consider the set $S=\{x\in[a,b]:f(x)=v\}$, which is not empty by assumption.

Since $S$ is nonempty and bounded, it has a supremum $s$. If $s\in S$, we are done.

Otherwise either $f(s)>v$ or $f(s)<v$. Suppose the former and take $\varepsilon=(f(s)-v)/2$. By continuity of $f$ at $s$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that, for $x\in[a,b]$ and $|x-s|<\delta$, we have $|f(x)-f(s)|<\varepsilon$.

This contradicts $s$ being the supremum, because it implies
$$
f(x)>\frac{f(s)+v}{2}>v
$$
but by definition of supremum there must exist $x\in[a,b]$, with $s-\delta<x<s$ such that $f(x)=v$. Contradiction.

Do similarly for the case $f(s)<v$.

A simpler way, provided you have proved that if the supremum doesn't belong to the set then there is a sequence in the set converging to the supremum, then take the sequence $(x_n)$ in $S$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=s$. Then, by continuity, $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=f(s)$, but the sequence $(f(x_n))$ is constantly $v$.

There's no need to do a proof for the minimum, because the function $g(x)=f(a+b-x)$ is continuous and $f(x)=v$ if and only if $g(x)=v$. However, the supremum of the set $\{x\in[a,b]:g(x)=v\}$ is the same as the infimum of $S$.